# Is there a Fraktur font that is thin like Helvetica Neue Light?

Tags: fonts, font-recommendation, blackletter

Is there any font of the [Fraktur](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraktur) style that has a light font style (like Helvetica Neue Light or Ultra Light)? Many Fraktur fonts I have seen on Internet are too thick.

Comment: Hi Ridho, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: @Vincent Thank you for the greeting! I've been a long time in other S.E. forum and this is my first time in Graphic Design S.E.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- By far the thinnest historical fraktur I am aware of is **[Elfen-Fraktur](http://typography.guru/journal/elfen-fraktur-blackletter/)** (literally *elf fraktur)*. A digitalisation is available [here](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/fdi/elfen-frakur/):

  [image: Elfen-Fraktur example]
- **[Astloch](http://ultrasparky.org/archives/2011/02/introducing_ast.html)** (literally *knothole)* is a recently designed blackletter font, which is even thinner, but lacks a long s and typical blackletter ligatures. Also, some letter shapes are not historical, e.g., *H, I, J, K* and *Z.*

  [image: Astloch example]
- [**Dequindre**](http://www.alexjacque.com/project/dequindre/) (available [here](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/alex-jacque/dequindre/)) is another recently designed thin blackletter font, which does contain the long s, but not all of the typical blackletter ligatures.

  [image: Dequindre example]

Comment: I stick the Elfen-Fraktur. However, how do you know that the font will be published? I don't see any information from FDI itself.

Comment: By the way, I also like the projects made by the Dequindre's artist. I hope the Dequindre will be released.

Comment: Thank you for the link! I will sign up to see the progress of the font itself.

Answer (score 2):

I have no knowledge of, nor have I ever been able to find, a truly light or thin Fraktur font. These are some of the pretty lightweights that I've found:

[Kabinett-Fraktur Regular](http://www.1001fonts.com/kabinett-fraktur-font.html) (aka Fraktur Mager) is pretty lightweight for a Fraktur font.

[Lautenbach](http://www.1001fonts.com/lautenbach-font.html#styles) is a more modern approach, not really a 'classic' Fraktur, but also more readable imho.

[Strassburg Fraktur](http://www.fontspace.com/peter-wiegel/strassburg-fraktur) is a truly lightweight Fraktur font.

[Space winning frax](http://www.fontspace.com/manfred-klein/space-winning-frax) is also a pretty lightweight Fraktur font, and features both round and long lowercase 's'.

Answer (score 1):

I am the designer of [Dequindre](http://www.alexjacque.com/project/dequindre/), a font mentioned in one of the other answers. I'll be releasing it soon (I neglected it as I was finishing up my MFA).

It will contain a historical long s and a number of ligatures (mostly of the *f_* variety). It has 355 glyphs and has the necessary accents to support a good number of languages, so for instance if you for some reason want to set some Icelandic in Dequindre, you’ll be able to.

Most of the glyphs are Fraktur in design, though I did take a few liberties, e.g., the *S* glyph is in Schwabacher style.

Comment: Can you add a small picture (one line of text), showing what the font looks like?

Comment: @Jacque That's good news! I'm looking forward to seeing your progress from now :-)